# Return duplicates when found in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I have a query to get a `SUM` total from a subquery like so:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(x.price),2) as "total" FROM (
   SELECT cd.name, MIN(tcgs.marketPrice) as "price" 
   FROM card_database cd
   INNER JOIN tcgplayer_cards tcgc ON tcgc.name = cd.name
   INNER JOIN tcgplayer_set_prices tcgs ON tcgc.productID = tcgs.productId
   WHERE (cd.id = 31374201 or cd.id = 31374201) 
   GROUP BY cd.name
) x
```

I want the subquery to add a new distinct row when duplicates are found in the `WHERE` clause;

Take this example:

```
   SELECT cd.name, MIN(tcgs.marketPrice) as "price" 
   FROM card_database cd
   INNER JOIN tcgplayer_cards tcgc ON tcgc.name = cd.name
   INNER JOIN tcgplayer_set_prices tcgs ON tcgc.productID = tcgs.productId
   WHERE (cd.id = 31374201) 
   GROUP BY cd.name
```

It has 1 `WHERE` condition and the output is;

[image]

However, if I modify it and add a duplicate `OR cd.id = 31374201` :

```
   SELECT cd.name, MIN(tcgs.marketPrice) as "price" 
   FROM card_database cd
   INNER JOIN tcgplayer_cards tcgc ON tcgc.name = cd.name
   INNER JOIN tcgplayer_set_prices tcgs ON tcgc.productID = tcgs.productId
   WHERE (cd.id = 31374201 OR cd.id = 31374201) 
   GROUP BY cd.name
```

Then I want the expected result to be two distinct columns so they can be summed in my original query:

[image]

So far, the `WHERE` clause seems to ignore/exclude duplicate entries when using `OR`.

I can do this in PHP but I'd like to know if there is a way to avoid that and do it directly in MySQL.

Comment: Since you are using `GROUP BY` for your aggregate function (`Min` here) you can't have duplicates records by changing the `WHERE` statement. The only work around i could think is to use `UNION` to 'x' query if you don't want to handle those by code. The cons here is that the query would cost 'x' times the time and the ressources to get them.

Comment: It's not ignoring the OR. The entire WHERE condition is tested against each row. Either the row is selected or it isn't.

Comment: @Barmar Makes sense. In that case, the solution is to essentially do this via `UNION` (as per @Frankich) or through my PHP code correct?

Comment: Yes, I don't think there's any better way. I suggest UNION because it's fewer calls to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by @Barmar and @Frankich, the query is not ignoring OR. The row is simply being selected.

As such, I had to rewrite the query using `UNION ALL`. Regular `UNION` would strip duplicates.

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(x.price),2) as "total" FROM (
   SELECT cd.name, MIN(tcgs.marketPrice) as "price" 
   FROM card_database cd
   INNER JOIN tcgplayer_cards tcgc ON tcgc.name = cd.name
   INNER JOIN tcgplayer_set_prices tcgs ON tcgc.productID = tcgs.productId
   WHERE (cd.id = 31374201) GROUP BY cd.name
   UNION ALL
   SELECT cd.name, MIN(tcgs.marketPrice) as "price" 
   FROM card_database cd
   INNER JOIN tcgplayer_cards tcgc ON tcgc.name = cd.name
   INNER JOIN tcgplayer_set_prices tcgs ON tcgc.productID = tcgs.productId
   WHERE (cd.id = 31374201) GROUP BY cd.name
) x
```